# Materials turn into solid color

Tags: materials

Whenever I make a material and assign it, it turns into solid color in material mode, and when I export it, it's materials are still solid color. How do I fix this? [image: The model]

Comment: This could be a lot of things, can you please share your blend file?

Comment: Is there a way for me to upload the file here?

Comment: We use [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for this purpose.

Comment: You can find the blend here: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=b0J0O08j" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/b0J0O08j/)